# Is the permuation check range in the PLONK Paper incorrect?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

From the [PLONK paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf).

On pages 19 & 20, the paper describes the prescribed permutation check in PLONK.

[image]

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

My question is about the Step 3 in the protocol which I have marked in red

I am interpreting $1 \le j < i$ as $j =1$ to $j = i-1$

So the $\prod$ equation becomes
$Z(\mathbf{g}^i) = \prod_{j=1}^{j=i-1} f'(\mathbf{g}^j)/g'(\mathbf{g}^j)$

I think this should be $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i}$ instead of $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i-1}$

My reasoning is as below shown with an example where $H$ is a subgroup of 4 elements, so $n = 4$ & $[n] = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ & $H = \{ \mathbf{g}, \mathbf{g}^2, \mathbf{g}^3, \mathbf{g}^4\}$

I think the end result in the proof in this case is to prove that

$f'(\mathbf{g})/g'(\mathbf{g}) \star f'(\mathbf{g}^2)/g'(\mathbf{g}^2) \star f'(\mathbf{g}^3)/g'(\mathbf{g}^3) \star f'(\mathbf{g}^4)/g'(\mathbf{g}^4) = 1 $

This has 4 $f'/g'$ terms multiplied with each other.

In the case of $n=4$, the prod range becomes
So the $\prod$ equation becomes
$\prod_{j=1}^{j=4-1}$ which is $\prod_{j=1}^{j=3}$

So $j=1$ to $j=3$ will get us only 3 terms multiplied by each other. But we need 4 terms so the prod range needs to be $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i}$ instead of $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i-1}$

Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument in the paper is correct. Verifying (a) confirms that $Z(g)=1$, verifying
$$Z(a)f'(a)=g'(a)Z(a\mathbf g)$$
for $a=\mathbf g,\mathbf g^2,\mathbf g^3\ldots \mathbf g^{n-1}$ then inductively confirms that
$$Z(\mathbf g^i)=\prod_{j=1}^{i-1}\frac{f'(\mathbf g^j)}{g'(\mathbf g^j)}$$
for $i=2,\ldots,n$.

Finally, verifying
$$Z(a)f'(a)=g'(a)Z(a\mathbf g)$$
for $a=\mathbf g^n$ confirms that
$$Z(\mathbf g^n)f'(\mathbf g^n)=g'(\mathbf g^n)Z(\mathbf g^{n+1})$$
which by the group order and also using the above inductive result confirms that
$$f'(\mathbf g^n)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{f'(\mathbf g^j)}{g'(\mathbf g^j)}=g'(\mathbf g^n)Z(\mathbf g)$$
which is the same as
$$\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{f'(\mathbf g^j)}{g'(\mathbf g^j)}=1$$
as required.

Comment: from your reply - "for $a=\mathbf g^n$ confirms that". However, if we use $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i-1}$, $a$ never becomes $\mathbf g^n$. As you wrote earlier, the values of $a$ which are used in 5(b) are $a=g,g^2,G^3\ldots,  g^{n-1}$. Only if we use $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i}$ will 5(b) be tried with $\mathbf g^n$

Comment: Or are you saying that after 5(a) & 5(b) are done for $\prod_{j=1}^{j=i-1}$, then there is a final step where 5(b) is done for $a = \mathbf g^n$. If so, why is this not a part of the original loop?

Comment: Is $a =\mathbf g^n$ done separately outside the loop?

Comment: Also,I found this in the next page they have this - https://imgur.com/ICzqPa2.png - In 5(b) - they don't show it for all $i \in [n]$, they show it only for upto $n-1$. So when they say "inductively' does it mean that they are saying because it's true for $i = 2$ to $n-1$, by induction, it's also true for $i = n$? - i.e. they are talking about proof by induction

Comment: In 5 b) the statement $Z(a)f'(a)=g'(a)Z(a\mathbf g)$ is checked for all $a\in H$ which is $a=\mathbf g^i$ for all $i\in[n]$.